# Hide current section on headerline of agenda frame

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I want to show a Agenda frame using the `\AtBeginSection[]` function. The normal Version shows a section title and the highlighted section title in the toc. I just want it to show Agenda as large frame title.

Example:

Current version:

---

Section 2

Agenda

---

- Section 1
- **Section 2**

...

---

What I want:

---

### Agenda

---

- Section 1
- **Section 2**

...

---

*update

solved by

```
\AtBeginSection[
\begingroup
\nosecinhead
    \begin{frame}
        ...
    \end{frame}
\endgroup
]
```

Comment: Is this question still active ?

Comment: just looked into my files and yes, solved by putting \nosecinhead in front of the slide definition --> \AtBeginSection[\nosecinhead ...]

Comment: Good to know. Could you update your question or add an anwser with a code snippet so other may benefit from your experience ?